# Do you need to learn language to learn Tableau other than SQL?

Tags: tableau-api, qlikview, 360-panorama

Do Tableau, Qlikview and Panorama require knowledge of a language other than SQL?

Comment: Firstly, stop shouting. Secondly, please read the help topics on [How To Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") Thirdly, in the case of QlikView, yes.

Answer (score 0):

In `Qlikview` you can use the wizard to import data and populate charts. This generates the script for you. Using the wizard however does limit you to basic functions.

The `Qlikview` load script is in part based off of `SQL` so many of the functions are identifiable.

Comment: That answer cover the load script side, but doesn't address the somewhat complicated way `QlikView` works to get data from the loaded info onto a dashboard. $ sign expansion and set analysis are topics in their own right to learn before you can leverage the data into useful applications.